# Subqueries / join on the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

I have a table that looks like the following

Table `tbl_veh`

```
VIN         Record    DateChange
11223344      123A    6/24/2012
11223344      121G    7/20/2013
11223344      2D54    2/24/2013
55445588      44D4    2/27/2012
55445588      855D    3/15/2013
```

So I would like to select the VIN and record but only for the most recent date. How would I do that?

So I would get back

```
11223344 and 121G
55445588 and 855D
```

Comment: You want just the top 2 recent records?

Comment: No all records.  The table I have has hundreds of records this is just a sample.

Comment: "but only for the most recent date" - How you decide what is the most recent date? `11223344 and 121G` and `55445588 and 855D` have **diffrent** dates.

Comment: @RanEldan - I think he means most recent date for the given `VIN`.

Comment: Correct, the latest record for each VIN

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL doesn't have CTE

Comment: I have mySQL for my DBMS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH [ranked] AS (
     SELECT VIN, Record, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY DateChange DESC, newid()) [rank]
     FROM tbl_veh)

SELECT VIN, Record
FROM [ranked]
WHERE [rank] = 1;
```

or "less complex" version (without using `CTE`):

```
SELECT VIN, Record
FROM (
    SELECT VIN, Record, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VIN ORDER BY DateChange DESC, newid()) [rank]
    FROM tbl_veh) as [ranked] 
WHERE [rank] = 1;
```

Comment: This is complex and I don't understand it but it works. Thanks

Comment: Not at all. I added a less complex version :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this? This only works if you have one Datechange per vim. If you have more than one, you'll need to make changes

```
Select tbl_veh.vin, tbl_veh.record
From tbl_veh
Inner join (select vin, max(Datechange) 
            from tbl_veh
             group by vin
            ) last 
     On last.vin = tbl_veh.vin
```

Comment: I would like to have this to work but it doesn't like the syntax